Python библиотеки для минимизаций булевых выражений на GPU
Подскажите python библиотеки для минимизаций булевых выражений на GPU. Кол-во булевых переменных в выражении может превышать 1000.
Я использую sympy, но у нее очень низкая производительность.
Библиотеки z3, dd, pyeda не отображают булевые выражения в читабельном виде. То есть вместо x&y отображают AND(x,y). Это очень не удобно при анализе булевых выражения при отладке. Также у этих библиотек я не видел поддержку GPU.

"То есть вместо x&y отображают AND(x,y)" - я предполагаю, что можно обходить полученное выражение и вручную выводить в нужном виде. То что в префиксной нотации по умолчанию выводит вместо более удобной вам инфиксной еще не говорит, что из-за этого нужно искать другую библиотеку.

Пытался сделать это, но код не заработал корректно. Хотя по идее такая функция по дефолту должны быть встроенной. Но все равно ищу решение с поддержкой GPU

В документации точно ничего такого нет?

Нет. Я не нашел

В общем, это два разных вопроса. Я уверен, что можно даже вручную вывести в нужном формате. По поводу поддержки GPU - не факт что такое вообще есть: GPU больше специализируется на обработке больших массивов однотипных данных, а не на сложной логике. Но это не точно, могу ошибаться.

думаю написать свой оптимизатор, но столкнулся что нет кроссплатформенной библиотеки для работы с gpu
